# BSOD error occurs randomly

Tags: bsod

Anyone familiar with this Error code ??

---

### DUMP FILE : [Dump file download](http://sdrv.ms/17cpHPN)

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   d1
  BCP1: 0000000000000028
  BCP2: 0000000000000002
  BCP3: 0000000000000000
  BCP4: FFFFF880018356FD
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  768_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\082013-19063-01.dmp
  C:\Users\Nair\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-119231-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the dump file.  Post a report from BlueScreenViewer a very helpful program

Comment: @abhilash sukumari Post dump> Might be a page file corruption or memory issue. http://www.faultwire.com/solutions/fatal_error_solutions.php

Comment: @Ramhound : I have edited the post and added the link for the dmp file.

Comment: The dump is no longer available for download